# Getting ssh-keys of my team via API. bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket, ssh-keys, bitbucket-api

everybody!

I'm trying to get ssh-keys of each member of my team.

I created new OAuth user in my account, successfully got an OAuth token and got my own ssh-key by handling an API:

`https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/users/{MYLOGIN}/ssh-keys`

But when I try to get a key of another member I got HTTP 403 forbidden.
I also have created an OAuth account in project settings but it hasn't done successfully too.

I have admin permission.
OAuth account has all possible Read permission.

Any suggestions? Is it possible to obtain ssh-keys of all our team?

Comment: If SSH keys belonged to a team it makes sense that you might have access to them in that context, if you are a team admin. However accessing other users' SSH keys isn't possible since you are not administering their user accounts, only the team(s) that they are a member of.